# How to do file uploads with Relay Modern mutations?

Tags: graphql, relay, relaymodern

I'm using `react-relay/compat 1.1.0` and I need to write a mutation with the ability to upload a file.
In Relay Classic you can use `getFiles()` to support file uploads in mutations:

```
class AddImageMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
   getMutation() {
     return Relay.QL`mutation{ introduceImage }`;
   }

   getFiles() {
     return {
       file: this.props.file,
     };
   }
   ...
}
```

But haven't found any trace of functionality for uploading files in [Relay Modern](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/relay-modern.html) docs:

```
const {commitMutation} = require('react-relay');

commitMutation(
  environment: Environment,
  config: {
    mutation: GraphQLTaggedNode,
    variables: Variables,
    onCompleted?: ?(response: ?Object) => void,
    onError?: ?(error: Error) => void,
    optimisticResponse?: ?() => Object,
    optimisticUpdater?: ?(store: RecordSourceSelectorProxy) => void,
    updater?: ?(store: RecordSourceSelectorProxy) => void,
    configs?: Array<RelayMutationConfig>,

    // files: ... ?
  },
);
```

Is that supported yet in relay modern? and if so, what's the way of doing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide the files as object `uploadables` in the `config` object for `commitMutation` and then implement the actual upload in your Network Layer, because the fetch request to the server has to be a  multipart form and not application/json.

See https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1844#issuecomment-316893590 for a complete example.

Comment: I don't get how to do it with `useMutation`

Answer (score 1):

Found this question as I just had the same one myself.

Not sure of the complete answer yet, but I'm starting to read through the Relay source and based on packages/relay-runtime/mutations/commitRelayModernMutation.js it looks like you can pass `uploadables` to your mutation.